# How to set NPM_BIN_PATH in django settings on cPanel?

Tags: python, django, npm, tailwind-css, django-tailwind

I have been trying to deploy my django project with django-tailwind on cPanel [Shared Hosting]. django-tailwind needs to have set NPM_BIN_PATH in settings.py. But in cPanel there is no npm path.